# Голосовое заполнение формы

Tags: javascript, form

Подскажите кто какие библиотеки знает для голосового заполнения HTML форм или у кого какие идеи и мысли есть насчет этого. Слышал что `x-webkit-speech` уже не работает ни в одном браузере. 
Интересуют оффлайн решения

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А вот если у Яндекса использовать SpeechKit? https://tech.yandex.ru/speechkit/jsapi/

Сразу дополню, вот такая реализация от самого Яндекса: https://tech.yandex.ru/speechkit/jsapi/doc/dg/concepts/speechRecognition-docpage/#textline

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ! Но по моему его можно использовать только в режиме онлайн а оффлайн никак ...

Comment: @AlexStassov думаю, о необходимости возможности работы оффлайн лучше написать в теле вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Первый же запрос в гугле выдал вот эту либу [pocketsphinx.js](https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js). Но вообще, оффлайн распознавание голоса вещь довольно сложная. Например, эта либа требует webworker`ов и WebAssembly. Хотя вы можете заморочиться и пересобрать на asm.js.

Рекомендую всё же использовать онлайн решения, они более простые в использовании.